# D3.js LineChart Tooltip & bisector

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add a tooltip on a linechart. I have an array of objects sorted on date and this field is already parsed and in a timestamp format. Objects look like:

```
{
    "province": "Brussels",
    "total_in_ecmo": 16,
    "new_in": 115,
    "total_in_resp": 109,
    "region": "Brussels",
    "geo_point_2d": [
      50.8365663663,
      4.36943412254
    ],
    "new_out": 91,
    "total_in_icu": 183,
    "nr_reporting": 15,
    "total_in": 1091,
    "date": Thu Oct 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100
}
```

on mouse-on linechart, I get the correct timestamp in x0 but the bisector is always returning me the value 1

```
vis.bisectDate = d3.bisector(d => {
  d.date
}).left
```

```
vis.g.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", vis.WIDTH)
  .attr("height", vis.HEIGHT)
  .on("mousemove", mousemove)

function mousemove() {
  const x0 = vis.x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0])
  const i = vis.bisectDate(vis.filteredData, x0, 1)
  console.log(i)
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You forgot to return a value in your bisector, you always return undefined. Remove the curly brackets or add `return` before `d.date`

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Thank you!! I added those curly brackets when I used console.log() to see what's happening. I added the return and it's working now ! :)